# GitHub Actions mysql service not working (Access denied)

Tags: mysql, github-actions

I try to use GitHub actions to check the functionality of my application. I'm using the mysql service and want to set up a database with a SQL file named `db_structure.sql`. But as soon as I run the action, it just gives me a `Access denied` error message.

Here's my full workflow:

```yaml
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  cypress_testing:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    services:
      mysql:
          image: mysql:5.7
          env:
              MYSQL_DATABASE: database
              MYSQL_USER: foo
              MYSQL_PASSWORD: bar
              MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: bar
          ports:
              - 3306
          options: --health-cmd="mysqladmin ping" --health-interval=10s --health-timeout=5s --health-retries=5

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install --save-dev
        
      - name: Create DB structure
        run: |
          sudo /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable mysql
          sudo systemctl enable mysql.service
          sudo systemctl start mysql.service
          sudo systemctl status mysql.service
          sudo mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -ufoo -pbar database < db_structure.sql

      # I would then run my tests here
```

And here is the full error message:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'foo'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I already tried adding `-h 127.0.0.1` to the `mysql` command. I also tried starting the service before running the mysql command.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: you might wan t to take a look of this post https://ovirium.com/blog/how-to-make-mysql-work-in-your-github-actions/

Comment: Blank page, now. This is why SO asks people to answer with snippets from third party pages and only use them as ref. Understand this is old.